# OSX Java app no longer finds Java resources folder by relative URL

Tags: java, macos, resources, classpath, osx-elcapitan

I have a Java app which I wrote with someone else several years ago. It's bundled as an OSX app, and up until recently our users were using Java 6. Now the users have upgraded to El Capitan and Java 8. I changed the build process for the app to use the [appbundler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) ant task to create the app bundle, and I can successfully launch the app in Java 8.

However, the treatment of resource files seems to have changed in a way that breaks our app. Previously we had resource files inside the bundle at `Contents/Java/resource`. We could access these resources with the URL `file:resource/someFile`, but this no longer works with Java 8.

I can fix that by putting the `resource` directory on my classpath and using something like `URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("resource/someFile");` However this only works for instances where the resource location is specified in Java code.

We have numerous xml and xsl files, in which the URL for various file resources appears as text properties. In every one of these instances, an exception is thrown because a resource cannot be found at `resource/someFile` as it used to be.

I need to find a way to make the app recognize these resources at a fixed relative path as it used to. It doesn't have to be in `Contents/Java/resource`. I can copy them anywhere, but I need to be able to specify their relative location as text properties at compile time.

I can write Java code that determines the base resource location and transforms the text files accordingly; but I'd much prefer to find a way to make it work as it did with Java 6.

Comment: If you use `System.out.prinlnt(new File(".").getCanonicalPath())` or `System.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))` to print out your current running context, you will find that your execution context is the `user.home` ... !  Yep, awesome ain't it.  So you know have (at least) two options.  Place the resources in well know location (`Library/Application Support/{your app}` might be one) or place the resources within the jar where you can load them via `getResource`.

Comment: Thanks. Is that a change from JarBundler to AppBuilder? Or a difference going from the Apple-developed JDK to the Oracle and OpenJDK versions?

Comment: I think this is a change in how appBundler works

Comment: I think you're right. I went into a directory inside the app bundle where my `resource` directory was and launched the app with java -jar path/to/jar and the resources were accessed successfully. So the JVM is fine; it must be the executable created by appBundler that sets the working directory outside the app bundle. I have to assume that's a bug. Surely no one would do that on purpose. I tried to create a bug report, but the only Oracle bug tracker I could find is for the JDK, and the appBundler doesn't fit into the categories. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: No, actually, from what I've read, this is actually deliberate (on Apple's part) based on the library that the app bundle uses to launch the JVM/app.  I think the app bundler is managed indepedently

Comment: I was being half-facetious, half-hopeful. I'm sure they had their reasons, but at least designating a property to select the working dir would be a useful enhancement. I submitted feedback to Apple to that effect, for what it's worth.